# D365fo: How to display info box when SellectAll is checked

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamic365

How do i display info when select all checkbox is checked or unchecked on a form grid in D365fo.

Using the linkActive() method on the DataSource and the MultiSelectionHelper class i was able to get selected record on the form grid control, but i need to trigger the info box when the user checked the select all on the header of the grid.